# Need explanation for one test case failed in Codility Peaks problem

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.

A peak is an array element which is larger than its neighbors. More precisely, it is an index P such that 0 < P < N − 1,  A[P − 1] < A[P] and A[P] > A[P + 1].

For example, the following array A:

```
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 2
A[2] = 3
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 3
A[5] = 4
A[6] = 1
A[7] = 2
A[8] = 3
A[9] = 4
A[10] = 6
A[11] = 2
```

has exactly three peaks: 3, 5, 10.

We want to divide this array into blocks containing the same number of elements. More precisely, we want to choose a number K that will yield the following blocks:

A[0], A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFmCQ.png), ..., A[K − 1],
A[K], A[K + 1], ..., A[2K − 1],
...
A[N − K], A[N − K + 1], ..., A[N − 1].
What's more, every block should contain at least one peak. Notice that extreme elements of the blocks (for example A[K − 1] or A[K]) can also be peaks, but only if they have both neighbors (including one in an adjacent blocks).
The goal is to find the maximum number of blocks into which the array A can be divided.

Array A can be divided into blocks as follows:

one block (1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2). This block contains three peaks.
two blocks (1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4) and (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2). Every block has a peak.
three blocks (1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 6, 2). Every block has a peak. Notice in particular that the first block (1, 2, 3, 4) has a peak at A[3], because A[2] < A[3] > A[4], even though A[4] is in the adjacent block.
However, array A cannot be divided into four blocks, (1, 2, 3), (4, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3) and (4, 6, 2), because the (1, 2, 3) blocks do not contain a peak. Notice in particular that the (4, 3, 4) block contains two peaks: A[3] and A[5].

The maximum number of blocks that array A can be divided into is three.

Write a function:

class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }

that, given a non-empty array A consisting of N integers, returns the maximum number of blocks into which A can be divided.

If A cannot be divided into some number of blocks, the function should return 0.

For example, given:

```
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 2
A[2] = 3
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 3
A[5] = 4
A[6] = 1
A[7] = 2
A[8] = 3
A[9] = 4
A[10] = 6
A[11] = 2
```

the function should return 3, as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000].

### My Understanding of the problem :

1. Each sub array should contain at least one peak
2. An element which forms a peak can be in an Adjacent sub array.
3. Return max possible sub arrays

### My Question

Consider Main Array : [0,1,0,1,0]

Possible sub arrays as per understanding : [0,1] [0,1,0]
Each subarray has a peak.
Subarray 1 [0,1] has peak element shared with adjacent array [**0**,1,0].
Subarray 2 [0,1,0] contains peak 0<1>0.

So max possible sub arrays are 2 but a test case in Codility returns max possible sub arrays as 1.

### Below is my code

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        
        int count=0,size=A.length;
        
        if(size<2)
            return 0;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
        
        for(int i=1;i<size-1;i++){
            
            if(A[i-1]<A[i] && A[i]>A[i+1]){
                count++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        
        return count;
        
        
    }
}
```

Test case which failed in Codility [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFmCQ.png)

I believe there is a gap in my understanding. Any help would be helpful :)

Comment: What is a peak? Something higher than both left and right side neighbours? If so, how does [0. 1] meet that requirement? How does any couple do so?

Comment: I have edited and added the information for adjacent block. please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to be congratulated to write a concise program to calculate the number of peaks. But the question is not to count the peaks.

It is to find the number of equal sized array and each having at least one peak. And a peak cannot be the first or last element as stated in the problem  **0 < P < N − 1**

Now quoting your question:
Consider Main Array : [0,1,0,1,0]

```
    Possible sub arrays as per understanding : [0,1] [0,1,0] Each subarray has a peak. Subarray 1 [0,1] has peak element shared with adjacent array [0,1,0]. Subarray 2 [0,1,0] contains peak 0<1>0.

    So max possible sub arrays are 2 but a test case in Codility returns max possible sub arrays as 1.
```

I see below issues:

- your sub array sizes are not equal
- array [0,1] does not have a peak

So, the array cannot be divided in equal parts each having a peak and hence only one array remains [0,1,0,1,0].

Comment: Thanks Anshuman :) I overlooked "equal size" constraint and regarding 0<P<N-1
I believe they are referring to Main array which means a peak will not present at first element and last element of the array but it is certainly possible in sub array. 
"Notice in particular that the first block (1, 2, 3, 4) has a peak at A[3], because A[2] < A[3] > A[4], even though A[4] is in the adjacent block."
A[3] is last element in subarray and it is considered as valid. 
If we remove constraint of equal size then subarray [0,1] in my example stated above can be considered as valid.

Answer (score 1):

https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training5KP2PK-P4M/

https://github.com/niall-oc/things/blob/master/codility/peaks.py

Breaking an array into even parts is another way of factorizing the length of the array.

#### Array of length 12

[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,]

#### Factors of 12.

The square root of 12 is 3.464... so start with 3 and irterate down to 1 and divide each number into 12.  This gives you a set of numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12}.

#### Process

Because of how a peak is defined you cannot have 12 peaks in this array so remove 12 from the set.  Starting *d* as the largest number divide the array int *d* parts. And check each part has a peak, if so then d is the maximum number of equal parts to all contain at least one peak.  If not so then iterate to the next largest divisor and try that until you find a solution.